# Formatting of elements inside a div element without effect of inherited css

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm showing a popup as a fixed div in random websites.

I need the content of the div to not be effected by the formatting of the page it resides in. The elements inside the div has inline CSS, and I want only the inline CSS to be effective, not inherited CSS.

One way to do that is to use iframe. I'm looking for other ways.

Options I'm considering:

1. A small javascript code which will run on all elements and reset inherited css.
   Is it possible? Can I tell cross-browser that an attribute is not created by inline css?
2. Javascript code to reset a group of attributes to all elements inside a div (for example all padding, margins etc. but still leave the style attributes from inline css?

any other creative idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

> The elements inside the div has inline
>   CSS, and I want only the inline CSS to
>   be effective, not inherited CSS

This is the default behavior. Inline CSS has the highest precedence.

AFAIK you won't be able to remove the inherited styles unless you override those.

Comment: yes but attributes which I didnt set inline get the inherited values ( that I want to avoid)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (though whether a practical one depends on your site) is to have a class called "resetCSS" or something like that which can be applied to a class. You use this class in a selector and in here you can set the base values for all the attributes you use (eg margins, fonts, etc.).

Then in use you apply that class to an element and that will reset everythign to default values which you can then override with your CSS.

The other alternative is to change all your current CSS to have a "styled content" class in the selector so that only content that is marked up specifically will receive the styling so that there is no chance of it being applied to the elements you don't want to have it.

Probably though if you want a div to have a particular style, even if that is the default, it is best to actually give it that style explicitly. If it was using the default anyway you lose nothing, if it was inheriting something else then you are setting it to what you want. Relying on default styles could bite you because there is no reason that any two browsers should have the same default styles at all.